# hipchat oauth token internal server error

Tags: oauth, token, hipchat

I follow hipchat site and try to get an add-on token
https://developer.atlassian.com/hipchat/guide/hipchat-rest-api/api-access-tokens?_ga=2.94621780.975509804.1497491262-871504840.1479901346#APIaccesstokens-Add-ongeneratedtokens

I have the following code:

```
import requests

secret = 'hipchat_secret'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(secret)}

url = 'https://api.hipchat.com/v2/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=send_notification+admin_room'

res = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

But it gives me a 500 Internal Server Error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was I used v1 token.

It works perfect when I switch to v2